# Lametric & Spotify api with PHP

Tags: php, spotify, lametric

I'm looking to create an application that can send the track played on spotify to my LAMETRIC clock
I found some good code in Github and I try to debug them but I'm stuck... can you help me to solve ???

The code works and I'm stuck on a loop that returns a value (null) but it is not returning that

https://github.com/WilliamVenner/LaMetric-Spotify here the code...

I create my application on spotify web and i get my client ID and my secret and my ready to use...
I create my application on lametric dev : it's up and running
I deploy my app here : https://c2x-services.com/lametric/currently_playing.php?show-artist=0&show-paused=0 is reachable

```
<?php
    
    $frames = array(
        "frames" => array(
            array(
                "text" => "?",
                "icon" => "i647"
            ),
        )
    );
    
    function output($text) {
        
        global $frames;
        
        $frames["frames"][0]["text"] = $text;
        
        echo(json_encode($frames));
        
    }

    if (!function_exists("getallheaders")) {
        
        // getallheaders is required to get the Authorization header as it does not appear
        // in $_SERVER or anywhere else. Therefore, try updating all of your software -
        // web server, PHP, etc. and try again.
        
        // This works absolutely fine on Apache and PHP 7.
        
        http_response_code("501 Not Implemented");
        error_log("https://github.com/WilliamVenner/LaMetric-Spotify/issues/2#issuecomment-325140347");
        return;
        
    }
    $headers = getallheaders();
    
    if (!isset($headers["Authorization"])) {
        output("X"); return;
    }
    
    $auth = $headers["Authorization"];
    
    require("inc/api.php");
    $Spotify = new Spotify($auth);
    $result = $Spotify -> API("me/player/currently-playing", false, true);
    
    if (isset($result["error"])) {
        
        if ($result["error"]["message"] == "invalid id") {
            
            output("[Local File]"); return;
            
        }
        
        if ($result["error"]["message"] == "The access token expired") {
            
            header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
            
            output("[X]"); return;
            
        }
        
        if ($result["error"]["message"] == "API rate limit exceeded") {
            
            output("Too many requests"); return;
            
        }
        
        output("!"); return;
        
    }
    
    if (!isset($result["item"])) {
        output("[X]"); return;
    }
    
    $track_info = $result["item"];
    
    if ($result["is_playing"] != true && $_GET["show-paused"] == "false") {
        
        output("[II]"); return;
        
    }
    
    $s = "";
    
    if ($_GET["show-paused"] == "true" && $result["is_playing"] == false) $s .= "[II] ";
    
    if ($_GET["show-artists"] == "true" && (($_GET["show-paused"] == "true" && $result["is_playing"] == false) || $result["is_playing"] == true)) {
        
        foreach($track_info["artists"] as $i => $artist) {
            
            if ($i > 0 && count($track_info["artists"]) > 1) $s .= ", ";
            
            $s .= $artist["name"];
            
        }
        
        $s .= " - ";
        
    }
    
    $s .= $track_info["name"];
    
    output($s);
    
?>
```

```
if (!isset($result["item"])) {
        output("[X]"); return;
    }
```

this return " null"

```
<?php
    
    class Spotify {
        
        private $auth;
        
        public function __construct($auth) {
            $this -> auth = $auth;
        }
        
        public function API($url, $post = false, $json = false) {
            
            if (!isset($this -> auth)) {
                throw new Exception('No authentication provided.');
                return;
            }
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/$url");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            
            if ($post)
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            else
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
            
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: ' . $this -> auth]);
            
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            
            if ($result)
                if ($json)
                    return json_decode($result,true);
                else
                    return $result;
            
            
        }
        
    }
    

?>
```

i'm stuck here .... my lametric return [X], i don't understand why...

here the API

Comment: So what are you actually getting in $result then? Make a var_dump.

Comment: @CBroe it return NULL {"frames":[{"text":"","icon":"50437","index":"0"}]}

Comment: I did not ask about your $frames variable, but what the actual result of your API call was.

Comment: @CBroe the same NULL

Comment: @CBroe here the code of my API call

Comment: So $result is null? Or are you talking about the result of json_decode?

Comment: when I add the add var_dump(json_decode), it return NULL @CBroe here the link [link](https://c2x-services.com/lametric/inc/api.php)

Comment: I asked you to check what $result contains. Not what the attempt to decode it as JSON results in (of course that will be null, if $result did not contain valid JSON to begin with.)

Comment: @CBroe $result contains nothing... its always NULL

Comment: Are you even passing any auth credentials? So far I assumed your `[X]` came from the place where you check on `$result["item"]` - but you are making that same output further up, when `$headers["Authorization"]` is not set.

Comment: @CBroe here the var_dump($headers) ["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"]=> string(1) "1" ["Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform"]=> string(7) ""macOS"" ["Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile"]=> string(2) "?0" ["Sec-Ch-Ua"]=>

Comment: @CBroe continue .... string(65) ""Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"" ["Cache-Control"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" ["X-Ovhrequest-Id"]=> string(32) "a19e62dcde929c8d3e0a5b0a8ea27413" ["X-Forwarded-Proto"]=> string(5) "

Comment: https" ["X-Forwarded-For"]=> string(14) "90.127.130.226" ["X-Predictor"]=> string(1) "1" ["Host"]=> string(16) "c2x-services.com" ["Authorization"]=> string(0) "" } {"frames":[{"text":"[X]","icon":"50437","index":"0"}]}

Comment: Okay, so the header is set, but its value is just an empty string. Then the `[X]` output is coming from the other place, because `$result["item"]` is not set - and that in turn is most likely because you did not pass any actual authorization data to this API.